# Does the Canon 800D (automatically) crop images made with in-camera HDR?

Tags: canon, hdr

I made some HDR images with the Canon D800, and it seems that they are cropped relative to an image made without HDR (same view, shot from the same place).

Does anyone have experience with this function on this model - have you noticed if it seems to crop the image? Thanks for your info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, well, I should have looked in the manual first, where it does say that the image area is smaller than when captured in normal mode. I might leave the question up, though, as it is a rather odd characteristic and might be useful to know for those intending to use in-camera HDR.

(In the German version, it is on page 102, as a tip marked with a ! -- what I'd love to know is *why*, as not all cameras do this with HDR.)

---

Just a quick update: One more thing I've noticed, which is that the preview in LiveView shows the shot with the same crop (at least it looks that way), so the user will likely get roughly the same composition as planned. So, it's not quite as inconvenient in terms of final product, as it seemed at first.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Stack Exchange explicitly encourages self-answered questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). My only suggestion here would be to give a reference to the page number in the manual which helped you.

Comment: How much is the crop? If it's just a little bit (5% or so) I expect it's there to deal with shift and rotation which may be needed for alignment of the three different exposures.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that a crop would be inherent. For example - if using a tripod - all 3 images would be perfectly aligned. Would the camera crop then?

Comment: @Corey — but then people would be complaining about how all their images come out different sizes. If you want control, do it out-of-camera.

Comment: Self-answered questions are fine, but I'm not sure asking follow up questions in said answer is optimal.

Comment: Corey, I quite agree, that one would think that a crop would not be part and parcel of the processing. It is indeed small although noticeable. @mattdm, what is even weirder, is that the image is re-sized automatically in-camera to be the same size (in pixel length and height) than a single-exposure image. Thus, the scene view changes but not the image size. Finally, sorry, Michael Clark, the question in my answer is rhetorical, as I expect the real reason why is part of the in-camera processing which is likely proprietal and thus a trade secret.

Comment: @Alexandra I'm not surprised at all — it's easy to resample to an arbitrary size as part of the whole process.